# change each element on hover

Tags: jquery, html, audio, hover

I have a image which changes the z-Index on hover and plays some sound:

```
<div class="portraitPanel">
    <img src="staticImage.jpg" class="saticImg">
    <img src="staticImage.gif" class="movingImg">
    <audio src="audio.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

That's the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".portraitPanel").hover(function(){
    $(".movingImg").css('z-index', 3000);
    $('audio')[0].play(); 
  });
  $(".portraitPanel").mouseout(function(){
    $(".movingImg").css('z-index', 0);
    $('audio')[0].stop(); 
  });
});
```

Okay, now I got it to work more or less. But I have multiple instances of that div. How do I only apply the jQuery Code on each div. Right now if I hover over one div, every audio on the page is playing (Yes, it sounds lovely). I tried to fiddle around with `this` but I cant get it to work. Any hints?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fczm0wt6/1/)

Comment: change it to like `$(this).find(".movingImg")` and `$(this).find("audio")` inside event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `context` to only search for elements inside the `parent`. And `hover` has two callbacks. One for `hover-in`, and one for `hover-out`. You don't need to register an extra `mouseout` event listener.

```
$(function() {
    $(".portraitPanel").hover(function() {
        var parent = $(this);
        $(".movingImg", parent).css('z-index', 3000);
        $('audio', parent)[0].play();
    }, function() {
        var parent = $(this);
        $(".movingImg", parent).css('z-index', 0);
        $('audio', parent)[0].stop();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".portraitPanel").hover(function() {
    $(".movingImg", this).addClass('red') //use this context to check which element gets the event
    //$(".movingImg", this).css('z-index', 3000);
    //$('audio', this)[0].play();
  });
  $(".portraitPanel").mouseout(function() {
    $(".movingImg", this).removeClass('red') //use this context to check which element gets the event
    //$(".movingImg", this).css('z-index', 0);
    //$('audio', this)[0].stop();
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portraitPanel">
  <img src="staticImage.jpg" class="saticImg">
  <img src="staticImage.gif" class="movingImg">
  <audio src="audio.mp3"></audio>
</div>
That's the jQuery

<div class="portraitPanel">
  <img src="staticImage.jpg" class="saticImg">
  <img src="staticImage.gif" class="movingImg">
  <audio src="audio.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

Use `this` context

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fczm0wt6/2/)**

1. use `on()` to attach events
2. use `$('.selector', context)` to specify a context for the selector
3. cache current `<audio>` on hover, to pause it on mouseleave

```js
var currentAudio;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".portraitPanel").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(".movingImg", this).css('z-index', 3000);
    currentAudio = $('audio', this)[0];
    currentAudio.play(); 
  }).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(".movingImg", this).css('z-index', 0);
    currentAudio.pause(); 
  });
});
```

```css
.portraitPanel {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.portraitPanel .saticImg {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.portraitPanel .movingImg {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portraitPanel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="saticImg">
    <img src="http://i.giphy.com/GvUb9lnnnsjYY.gif" class="movingImg">
    <audio src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_ly8ox6tsxV1rnkkvko1.mp3"></audio>
</div>

<div class="portraitPanel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/123" class="saticImg">
    <img src="http://i.giphy.com/GvUb9lnnnsjYY.gif" class="movingImg">
    <audio src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_ly8ox6tsxV1rnkkvko1.mp3"></audio>
</div>

<div class="portraitPanel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/672" class="saticImg">
    <img src="http://i.giphy.com/GvUb9lnnnsjYY.gif" class="movingImg">
    <audio src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_ly8ox6tsxV1rnkkvko1.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```